# Not sharing single instance of jQuery/simple assignment failing?

Tags: webpack, babeljs, mjs

I don't know how to explain this one. I'm trying to debug `import 'datatables.net'` isn't setting `$.fn.dataTable`. My theory was that I have 2 copies of `jquery`.

To debug I added

```
$.poop = 345
$.fn.somethingUnique = 123
```

*before*

```
import factory from 'datatables.net'
```

Then I added a break statement inside `jquery.dataTables.mjs` which appears to be the file that webpack is loading.

[image]

If you look at the "Watch" on the right there (in Chrome devtools) you will see `$.poop` is undefined but `jQuery.poop` is set as expected.

If you look on the left there, there's a line `let $ = jQuery;`

So if they're equivalent... how can they not be equivalent? What's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

I think that was exactly it, `datatables.net` was importing jQuery 3. DevTools was tricking me by showing the uncompiled code.

Adding

```
    "resolutions": {
        "jquery": "^2"
    },
```

to `package.json` fixed it for me (using yarn 3.x)